# How to start and stop Server Side Event script from server

Tags: javascript, php

I'm following the WC3 tutorial on server side events and am interested to know if i can use them to only deliver events/notifications when a php script is actually running, i.e. executing code. Ideally i'd like to use server side events to show script execution progress and avoid server polling altogether.

Currently my very simple client code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Getting server updates</h1>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {
    var source = new EventSource("https://xyz.php");
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
    };
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and my client code is as follows:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

function send_message() 
{
$time = date('r');
echo "data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n";
flush();
} 

send_message();

?>
```

I know the above is an extremely simple example however I can't figure out how to start and stop the notifications and, in turn only do this when a server side script is running - a simple server script example would be to only send notifications every second when a timer counts from 1 to 10 and then stop.

Is this at all possible?